# Creating or popping up a dialog in a Thread from nib file in cocoa

Tags: objective-c

I need to create a dialog from a thread.
Im loading a nib file within the thread using the "initwithwindowNibName" and trying to popup the dialog using "[nsapp runmodalforwindow]",but the dialog is not popping up..

Please  help me out.

Comment: Hey some boday can help out rite...r every one so busy???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AppKit, the GUI framework, is not thread safe. In order for things to work properly, you (almost) always need to update GUI classes from the main thread

— [Dave Dribin, Invoke on Main Thread](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/05/22/invoke_on_main_thread/)

Basically, you'll want to do something like:

```
[objectThatShowsTheDialog performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showTheDialog:)
                                           withObject:anObject
                                        waitUntilDone:NO];
```

to call the code that puts up the dialog on the the main thread.